# How to localize FormOverlay component

Tags: vaadin-flow

Title and Description properties has setters for labels but username, password and buttons dont have.

Could I set localized text to these properties?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the [login overlay](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-login/java-examples), you can localize it through `LoginOverlay#setI18n`. For example:

```
LoginOverlay overlay = new LoginOverlay();
LoginI18n i18n = LoginI18n.createDefault();
i18n.getHeader().setTitle("My title");
i18n.getForm().setUsername("User");
i18n.getForm().setPassword("Pass");
i18n.setAdditionalInformation("Additional info");
i18n.getErrorMessage().setTitle("It's a disaster!!!");
overlay.setI18n(i18n);
```